# T-SQL: Cursor with table and Column Params

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, cursor

Writing a Stored Procedure which has two varchar parameters for column and table name. I want to use these parameters within a Cursor.

The following compiles (code snippet):

```
...
ALTER PROC [sp_test]( 
@TabName VARCHAR(MAX),
@ColName VARCHAR(MAX))
AS

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @ColName + 'FROM ' + @TabName + 'ORDER BY ' + @ColName
EXEC ('DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR ' + @SQL)
...
```

However, when I attempt to execute the query with arguments I get the errors:

```
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
  'BY'.
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_testCrypt, Line 89 A
  cursor with the name 'curs' does not exist.
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State
  1, Procedure sp_testCrypt, Line 96 A cursor with the name 'curs' does
  not exist.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Usually a cursor is an overkill, and dynamic-sql cursors are, if anything, worse.

Comment: Its only a basic and quick program so performance is not an issue. Also As mentioned above, it is a 'code snippet' not full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space before "ORDER" 
E.g : ' ORDER BY '

Comment: Oh dear, can't believe that was the problem, I missed a space on the "From" and "Order By", thanks!

Comment: Nope, or you can use this ; + @TabName + ' ' + 'ORDER BY '

Comment: @Ouscux: you can use `@TabName + ' ORDER BY '`